Name repeated twice on BRP
I just got my BRP however my name has been printed twice. In my passport I do not have a surname, only a given name. However, when I received my BRP my name was both in the given name and surname column.
For example in my passport -
Surname - blank
Given name - XY
In my BRP the name reads - ‘XY XY’.
Would this create an issue when travelling as my name is repeated twice whereas in passport it’s once? Should I ask for a replacement BRP?
Any kind of help would be appreciated.
Thank you

Have had a friend visa printed first name and again his first name since he doesn’t have a last name so probably it’s how it is

What did UKVI say when you asked them?

@SaranshSharma and they didn’t have any issues in travelling?

Same old reply that they would get back in 20 days time

@Traveller This kind of comment is thoroughly unhelpful. Anyone who's ever dealt with the Home Office know they barely ever give a useful response to anything.

@MJeffryes Maybe, however posting a question without including the outcome of at least some prior research is also unhelpful to potential respondents.

@Traveller Sure, but phoning the Home Office will most likely leave you with less information than you had before you started the call. If everyone asking questions about UK visas phones the helpline first, the only effect will be enriching the helpline contractor. I would not recommend doing it in almost any circumstance. In terms of prior research, I'm not aware of any public guidance on the question OP asked.

@TalhaAhmed no they didn’t .
